# If a function has a uniform Lipschitz constant on an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$, is it globally Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

I had a question regarding locally and globally Lipschitz functions.

Suppose there exist some real $\delta > 0$ and $M > 0$ such that $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x - y|$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $|x - y| < \delta$. That is, suppose $f$ is locally Lipschitz, and the same Lipschitz constant works for all small enough neighborhoods of $\mathbb{R}$. Then is the function globally Lipschitz too? If not, what is a counterexample?

I know that if the function is everywhere differentiable, the above condition implies its derivative is bounded, and thus it must be globally Lipschitz, so a counterexample must not be differentiable. Also, the image of a counterexample would have to be unbounded in $\mathbb{R}$, since if for all $M' \geq M$ we have $|f(x) - f(y)| > M'|x - y|$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, we know this is only possible if $|x - y| \geq \delta$ by the condition above, so we find $|f(x) - f(y)| > M'\delta$ for all $M' \geq M$ and some $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, and it follows from here that the image must be unbounded since $M'\delta \to \infty$ as $M' \to \infty$. I also know that if the domain was a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then we could just recursively take bigger Lipschitz constants to connect the neighborhoods and cover the whole domain with a single Lipschitz constant, but I don't see how this would apply to an unbounded domain like all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there more to this condition/argument that I am missing?

Thanks.

Edit: Also, as a follow-up question, if instead $\delta$ depended on $y$ (or equivalently $x$) then would this even imply uniform continuity, or would it just be imply local continuity?

Comment: For a general metric space, I think it would be ok to show it on countable covers, but otherwise I think you need the choice axiom. But since $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of compact spaces it can be shown

Comment: For any $x<y$, find $x=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=y$ so that $|t_{i}-t_{i-1}|<\delta$. Then apply the local Lipschitz continuity to each $[t_{i-1},t_i]$ and then combine them together.

Comment: You could try to show that it is true for the restriction of $f$ to $[-n,n]$ for example, then you would have the result since $M$ is constant

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace For general metric spaces it's false, see for instance $X=\Bbb N$ with Euclidean distance, $\delta=\frac12$, $M=1$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Yes you need homogeneity sorry it would be for normed convex spaces then.

Comment: @SangchulLee When I combine them together (presumably via the triangle inequality?) can't I end up getting a larger Lipschitz constant than $M$ for $(x, y)$ if $|x - y| \geq \delta$? How would I ensure that just $M$ suffices for the whole combination, or that continuingly doing this for the whole domain does not make the constant blow up to $\infty$?

Comment: That's the neat part, you don't. :) Try to write down everything and discover this beauty for yourself, too!

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. The metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is so nice that if you choose $x < z < y$ WLOG then because $|x - y| = |x - z| + |y - z|$ exactly my Lipschitz constant doesn't blow up. Is that the idea?

Comment: Just posted an answer but I've deleted as it seems from discussion maybe @MathNeophyte you wish to answer this one yourself - you seem to have the idea.  If  not I'm happy to repost.

Comment: Post your answer if you want to. I actually have to do some combinatorics homework today anyway so I'm probably not going to write up the whole proof anytime soon.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace we won't need the axiom of choice to extend to normed spaces and geodesic metric spaces - the proof from $\mathbb R$ carries over since we only need to focus attention on a segment joining $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenters have already answered in the affirmative, but let me give a rigorous answer to your follow-up as well.

If $\delta$ depends on $x$, we still obtain a global Lipschitz condition.  That is, as long as each $x$ has a $\delta_x$ for which $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta_x$, then $f$ is globally $M$-Lipschitz.

To see this, let $x,y\in \mathbb R$, and define $S:=\{z\in[x,y]\mid |f(x)-f(z)|\leq M|x-z|\}$.

Let $z=\sup(S)$, with $z\in S$ since $S$ is closed by continuity of $f$.*

If $y\neq z$, then choosing $z'\in (z,y)$ with $|z'-z|<\delta_z$, we have

\begin{align*}
|f(x) - f(z')| &\leq |f(x)-f(z)| + |f(z)-f(z')|\\
&\leq M|x-z|+M|z-z'|=M|x-z'|,
\end{align*}
so that $z'\in S$, contradicting that $z'>z=\sup(S)$.

Therefore $y=z\in S$, so the Lipschitz condition is satisfied.

##### Remark

Though the question was stated for $\mathbb R$, the proof immediately extends to the setting where $f\colon X\to Y$ is a map between metric spaces, and $X$ is a geodesic metric space (every two points can be joined by an isometric image of an interval).  In particular, it holds whenever the domain is any convex subset of a normed vector space.

##### *Clarification

To see $S$ is closed, note that it is the inverse image of the closed set $(-\infty,0]$ under the continuous map $z\mapsto |f(x)-f(z)|-M|x-z|$, defined on $[x,y]$. If you haven't had point-set topology, you can also just observe that if $|f(x)-f(z_i)|\leq M|x-z_i|$ for a sequence $z_i\to z$, then from sequential definition of continuity, $$|f(x)-f(z)|=\lim_{i\to\infty} |f(x)-f(z_i)|\leq\lim_{i\to \infty} M|x-z_i|=M|x-z|.$$

Comment: I think there might be a typo in the definition of $S$ considering the condition does not involve $z$. I am assuming it instead should be the set of all $z \in [x, y]$ such that $|f(x) - f(z)| > M|z - x|$ for some $x \in [x, y]$ or something like that?

Comment: Also, I'm not quite sure what relatively open means here or how it ties into the proof (sorry I haven't properly taken any topology), but I think I  get the point of the proof is that if you have $M$-Lipschitz continuity on an open interval $I$ and $M$-Lipschitz continuity at the boundary points of $I$ (where $M$ is the same) then you can extend the open interval arbitrarily to cover the whole domain space, and the point of the infimum and contradiction argument is to formally show that you can cover the whole space, correct?

Comment: @MathNeophyte yes, sorry about the typo.  As for relatively open, that just means it’s open when viewed as a subset of $[x,y]$, meaning it’s allowed to include an endpoint of $[x,y]$.  I could have avoided that business if I’d defined things a bit differently, but I wanted to give an argument that also generalized to the case where the domain wasn’t all of $\mathbb R$.  The real point of the infimum and contradiction argument was just to avoid a covering argument entirely, since that’s a little more awkward when the $\delta$s are different for each point.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on why the continuity of $f$ makes $S$ open in the subspace Topology of $[x, y]$. Do we know the image of $S$ is open for some reason, or what is the argument there? What stops it from just being a single element set even (we can see by definition $x$ is not included so at least only $y$ is)?

Comment: @MathNeophyte $S$ is the inverse image of $(0,\infty)$ under the map $z\mapsto  |f(x)-f(z)|-M|x-z|$.  As the inverse image of an open set under a continuous map, it is open.  (This is actually the most general definition of continuity, which you will learn when you take topology - it is equivalent to the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition).  You could also argue $z:=\inf(S)\notin S$ using limits and the limit definition of continuity, if you want, by expressing $z$ as a limit of points $z_i<z$ satisfying $|f(x)-f(z_i)|\leq M|x-z_i|$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of the image of $S$ under $f$ for some reason but I see that map is also continuous and works. Also I think I see what you mean that since $z > x$ and it's a limit of those $z_i$ as you say (by $\inf$ definition), there is a $z_i \in (z - \delta_z, z + \delta_z)$ so $M$-Lipschitzness on $(z - \delta_z, z + \delta_z)$ means $|f(z) - f(x)| \leq M|x - z|$ as well by the triangle inequality.  I think it would be worth including one or both of these arguments in the proof though, in case there are other realtively mathematically unexperienced people reading.

Comment: More specifically there is a $z_i \in (z - \delta_z, z) \cap [x, y]$ so $x \leq z_i < z$ for the triangle inequality argument.

Comment: Now that I fully get it I see how this argument by contradiction is much better than trying to formalize an argument with a potentially uncountable cover. I know you can show that you have $M$-lipschitzness on a union of any two overlapping intervals of $M$-Lipschitness, and you can extend that to a countable union by induction, but then would you need transfinite induction or something to extend it to all of the domain since the cover might be uncountable?

Comment: @MathNeophyte we could actually use compactness to get a finite subcover over the relevant interval, if we did a covering argument, so no transfinite induction or anything like that - the reason why I didn't want to do the covering argument was more that our condition is a pointwise one, rather than a local one, i.e., we don't immediately know it's Lipschitz on $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, since our condition doesn't say we can choose two arbitrary points in $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$, it says one of the points must be $x$ itself.  the argument can still work but you have to be quite a bit more careful.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion of including the limit of $z_i$ argument in the actual proof, I will have to think about that, I might not get a chance to revisit this immediately but if I think of a good way to include it in the main proof I'll revise at some point.

Comment: If you want to include the preimage of $(0, \infty)$ argument instead since that's basically how it is now, I think that would also be fine. I think it's just worth mentioning either argument explicitly so the proof is more readily complete to readers.

Comment: As for the pointwise vs local issue, I was thinking that since for any $z$ you can show $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x - y|$ for all $x, y \in (z - \delta_z, z + \delta_z)$ where $x < z < y$ you could turn it into a local property easily but the issue is actually when $x$ and $y$ are on the same side of $z$ so you're right it's thornier than I thought.

Comment: I think you could start with an arbitrary $x$ in domain and extend $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x - y|$ from all $y \in (x - \delta_x, x + \delta_x)$ to all $y$ in the domain by recursively using the pointwise property and triangle inequality with the boundary points of your interval that you already have it for (eg let $x_{\pm} = x \pm \delta_x$ and show it works for $y = x_{\pm}$ and thus for $y \in (x_- - \delta_{x_-}, x_+  + \delta_{x_+})$, etc.), but then I don't think this is really a covering argument anymore and I don't really know how to show that this would extend it to all of the domain.

Comment: I guess you would have to consider the set of all points $y > x$ that it doesn't work for and show that doesn't have an $\inf$  giving a contradiction, and similarly $y < x$ has no $\sup$, so it would be essentially the same as this proof but less efficient anyway.

Comment: @MathNeophyte Thanks for your earlier suggested edit.  In the end, I decided to reorganize just a bit (I think its a little easier to see if you define $S$ the opposite way as a closed set and take $z$ as a sup, rather than inf) and since I like to keep the main argument on the brief side to the extent possible, I put a clarification in a concluding remark to address any confusion about how we know $S$ is closed.